# Display matrix with alternate 0 and 1 for each inner matrix

Tags: c#, puzzle

What will be algo for print a matrix of the order n(given as input by user) and always odd number.

Example: In user give n = 7 
Output will be
1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  0  0  0  0  0  1
1  0  1  1  1  0  1
1  0  1  0  1  0  1
1  0  1  1  1  0  1
1  0  0  0  0  0  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1

Comment: As usual: what have you tried so far?

Comment: It is not a puzzle, actually. It is very simple task even for newbie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider we want to print point (x, y) (the center is (0, 0)). Take max(abs(x), abs(y)) and look if it is odd or even and print 0 for even and 1 for odd.

You should iterate from y = n / 2 to y = - n / 2 and the trough x = - n / 2 to x = n / 2

Sorry for my poor English